# how to keep listbox item selected state?

Tags: listbox, tcl, tk-toolkit

```
global SelectMode
set SelectMode mode1
set FunList {Func1 Func2 Func3}
listbox .lb -listvariable FunList
bind .lb <<ListboxSelect>> {puts [.lb curselection]}
ttk::combobox .com -values {mode1 mode2 mode3} -textvariable SelectMode
pack .lb
pack .com
```

when I first select the item (choose "Func2" as example) in the listbox and then select the mode in the combobox, then I get an unexpected empty string output like below:

```
1
"" (unneeded)
```

how to keep the listbox item selected state and unaffected by the combobox? Thanks

Comment: FWIW, I can't reproduce this problem. Presumably something else not in this code is causing the extra empty string.

Comment: @Peter Lewerin ehm... I tried again in the Linux, the extra empty string will not appear. That's fine, and do you have any idea about keep displaying the listbox item selected state, not need to output string?

Comment: Well, technically the selection state *is* displayed in the listbox widget already,  but how about using the same binding as now but setting the text of a label widget instead of outputting the selection?

Answer (score 0):

The `.lb curselection` command leverages the window manager focus to know what is selected. Since the window manager is busy with another element (the combobox in this case), it can't see that the listbox has a selection. The solution is to write a procedure to keep track of the listbox selection. And update a variable when the selection is changed.

```
global SelectMode
lb_selection = ""
set SelectMode mode1
set FunList {Func1 Func2 Func3}
listbox .lb -listvariable FunList
bind .lb <<ListboxSelect>> {ListSelectionChanged %W}
ttk::combobox .com -values {mode1 mode2 mode3} -textvariable SelectMode
pack .lb
pack .com

# Procedure bound to <<ListboxSelect>> virtual event.
proc ListSelectionChanged { listbox } {
    global lb_selection
    set lb_selection [$listbox curselection]
}

# Procedure to repeatedly print the selection status of the listbox
proc printLBSelection { } {
    global lb_selection
    puts $lb_selection
    after 2000 printLBSelection
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but I don't want to repeatedly print the selection status, i just want to keep displaying that the listbox has a selection. Follow your advice,  I add the "$listbox selection set $lb_selection" in the printLBSelection, it seems work, but if there any other workaround without use "after 2000 printLBSelection"? Thanks.

Comment: @Peter Lewerin comment above may be what you're looking for overall. It would work a little like a combobox in that the label could store the current listbox selection. Instead of a global variable, use a StringVar as the label's textvariable, and each time the listbox value changes, call the .set() method on the label's variable to update the selection. Then you don't need to print anything out -- the answer will be more visible on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [exportselection](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/options.htm#M-exportselection) option to false to prevent the selection from changing when a different widget has a selection.

```
listbox .lb -listvariable FunList -exportselection false
```

Comment: Thanks! That's really what I want!